# How can I send the messages to all the users whose usernames are listed in a post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently, I’m using this code in order to send a notification mail to the user whose username is listed in a post.

```
target_user = params[:comment][:body].scan(/(?<=^@)\w+(?=[\s|~])/).first
@target_user = User.find_by_username(target_user)
current_user.send_message(@target_user, body, subject)
```

However, the problem is that it cannot send the messages to more than one person:(

How can I make change my code to achieve that?

Assuming the content of **params[:comment][:body]** is just like this

```
@JohnWhite @EmilyBrown @AdamKaylor
```

I want to fetch all 3 users objects, and repeat

> current_user.send_message(@target_user, body, subject)

for 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 possible ways of doing it, depending upon how you want to use `String#scan`  see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan

Without a block scan will return an array of matches,  so if you drop the .first  you can just iterate over the array and send the notification

```
target_users = params[:comment][:body].scan(/(?<=@)\w+(?=[\s|~])/)
target_users.each do |target_user|
    @target_user = User.find_by_username(target_user)
    current_user.send_message(@target_user, body, subject)
end
```

Or if you pass a block to scan you can just work on each match as you find it.

```
 params[:comment][:body].scan(/(?<=@)\w+(?=[\s|~])/) do |target_user|
     @target_user = User.find_by_username(target_user)
     current_user.send_message(@target_user, body, subject)
 end
```

both should do the same thing, but I haven't tested either.

--edit--

Remove the ^ anchor on the @ so it pulls all the @mentions from the string, not only if the are the first on the line.

```
>> "dfdfd @JohnWhite @EmilyBrown test".scan(/(?<=@)\w+(?=[\s|~])/)
=> ["JohnWhite", "EmilyBrown"]
```

Comment: Thanks I tried with `@JohnWhite @EmilyBrown` but it didn't work:(

Comment: There's no error. It just recognizes only 1st `@JohnWhite` and it won't fetch 2nd `@EmilyBrown`:(

Comment: Here I post `@JohnWhite @EmilyBrown test`. This results that it only send a message to @JohnWhite

Comment: see my edit.  I didn't bother testing your regex, since I assumed it worked. But the ^@ means start of string so it would only match the @ if it was at the start of the line,  changing the regex to match anywhere will pull any @usernames out, and then should iterate.